# Google mail of a laravel project not working in cpanel

Tags: laravel, email, gmail, cpanel

I was using the following lines in .env file when I was on the localhost and everything was working:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myaddress@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypwd
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

But the moment I hosted the laravel project through cpanel it shows the following error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)
```

I then tried with the following .env file, the form sends the mail but I cant actually receive anything:

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465 //tried amending it to 587
MAIL_USERNAME=myaddress@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypwd
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl //tried amending it to tsl when I changed the port to 587 but still same issue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t send mail without enabling less secure apps in google with third-party apps. So let's enable it.

1. Log in your Gmail account which you want to use for this
2. Open URL https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
3. If it is OFF then make it ON.

Your .env file will then look something like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ENTER_YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS(GMAIL)
MAIL_PASSWORD=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after you make changes in your .env file.

Comment: I exactly did what you just told me but still same error shows